# Axios delete from mysql db gives error 404

Tags: mysql, reactjs, axios, react-props

I get error when I try to delete a record from the database:

Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 404', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Code

```
 Axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/api/delete/rec', { data: props.recipe[0].ID }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    })
```

DB

```
app.get('/api/delete/rec', (req, res) => {
const dataID = req.body.data;

const sqlSelect = "DELETE FROM `recipes` WHERE ID = ?";

db.query(sqlSelect, dataID, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log(err);
});
```

})

When I temporarily change the questionmark to the ID in the dB it actually deletes it. So I assume it's an issue with Axios?

Comment: I think axios does not actully send any data in delete operations. Maybe you need to change the endpoint and send the id in the uri itself: `/api/delete/rec/ID`

Comment: Tried but the same error

Comment: have you checked that the id is actually reaching the controller?

Comment: Yes it is. Even this doesn't work: Axios.delete('http://localhost:3001/api/delete/rec/3');

Comment: But when I go to http://localhost:3001/api/delete/rec/3 in my browser, it works and deletes the record from the database...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

current code:
`app.get('/api/delete/rec', (req, res) => {`

proposed solution:
`app.delete('/api/delete/rec', (req, res) => {`